# Can I use a pointer to an object of a type allocated dynamically and use it "safely" as a variable length array?

Tags: c++

Can I use a pointer to an object of type T (which is allocated dynamically on free store), and use it as a pointer to the first element of an array in a "safe" (not undefined) manner?

I know it wouldn't be "safe" to use it like this (suppose T is int):

```
int* pi = new int{5};
pi[1] = 10;
```

So here, I guess the behavior is undefined here; &pi[1] is not owned by pi so it can be overridden?.

Is there a way to do such a thing safely?

Comment: You did not allocate an array, so using it as an array doesn't make sense

Comment: `new int{5}` creates a *single* `int` value, and initializes it to the value `5`. `pi[1]` will be out of bounds and lead to *undefined behavior*.

Comment: what exactly do you want to do? If you need an array or a vector, why not use one?

Comment: Sounds like an XY problem.  What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: As long as the consuming code does not access "the array" beyond the first element, this is fine. It is a common idiom in OpenGL code, for example: `glCreateBuffers(1, &myBuf)`.

Comment: A pointer to a single object can be considered as an array of only one single element. As such only index `0` is possible to use. Any other index will be out of bounds, and access (reading or writing) to that "element" will lead to undefined behavior.

Comment: As a rule of thumb comparing pointer against "one past" is generally fine, without dereferencing it of course. Specifics differ depending on C++ version. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @NathanOliver just out of curiosity actually, learning the language basics :)

Comment: It is OK to be curious, but the question still need to be clear enough. I still have difficulty figuring out what you actually meant to ask.

Comment: @WeijunZhou I am trying to have a variable length array. For example if I created an array 'a1' of length n, initialized it, used it, then decided to keep the values of this n elements and add another element to the end and make it of length n+1. Is there a way to do this without creating another array 'a2' of length n+1, copying first n elements of a1 to a2 and using a2.

Comment: `std::vector` is what you want.  You can make it any size you want and add and subtract elements as you want.

Comment: Then you should ask that instead. Are you looking for flexible array member at the end of a struct in C++? There are ways to do that, although not recommended.

Comment: It seems you are looking for `realloc` equivalent in C++. No, there are nothing equivalent to `realloc` in C++ that properly handles constructors and destructors. You can use `std::realloc` at your own risk. Of course, as already commented, `std::vector` should be the solution to your actual problem most of the time.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude "A pointer to a single object can be considered as an array of only one single element" is it also true with respect to pointer arithmetic (I thought that doing +1 on the object address in this case would be UB, but the rules are a bit tricky and I don't remember them well)

Comment: There is no difference between a pointer to a dynamically allocated object and a pointer to any other object. That is, your code is as meaningful as `int x = 5; int* pi = &x; pi[1] = 10;`.

Comment: @Raildex -- re: "using it as an array doesn't make sense" -- yes, and no. From a design perspective it's not really an array. But C and C++ define indexing in a way that makes `pi[0]` valid and well defined. `pi[0]` is defined to mean `*(pi + 0)`, which is `*pi`. So it's not unreasonable to think of `pi` as an array with one element. That makes it easier to reason about an array whose size is determined at runtime: `int *p = new int[something]` is valid for any non-negative value of `something`. Yes, including 0.

Comment: I would recommend use of `auto p = std::make_unique<int[]>(5);` or more flexible  `auto v = std::vector<int>(5);`

Comment: The use of new/delete in current C++ is not recommended (they are the cause of too many memory leaks). Either use std::vector for dynamic allocation of arrays or use std::make_unique as suggested. The fact that a lot of training material still uses new/delete is because it has never been updated since C++11 was released. Read [R.11 Avoid calling new/delete explictly](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#r11-avoid-calling-new-and-delete-explicitly) from the C++ core guidelines.

Comment: Also with std::vector you can use `at(1)` instead of `[1]` and it will give you an error that you accessed your "array" out of bounds. So I guess the summary is just don't write code like that.

Comment: did you want to use `new T[count]`? though you should better use `std::vector<T>` in this case

Comment: @PeteBecker say that again when you use `new T` but `delete[] T` or `new[] T` and `delete T`. According to you that would be defined behaviour.

Comment: @molbdnilo I have thought that the size of a function's stack frame is fixed at run-time (determined at compile time), hence the reason (that I thought) size of an array must be a constant expression. So I don't think variable length array in the stack is possible?

Comment: @Raildex -- huh? You always have to match `new` with `delete` and `new[]` with `delete[]`. That has nothing to do with what I said. Read my comment again; you'll see that it talks about the meaning of the `[]` operator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here

```
int* pi = new int{5};
```

`pi` is a pointer to a single integer with value `5`. As pointed out in a comment, there is no fundamental difference between that pointer and a pointer to a integer that was not dynamically allocated:

```
int x = 5;
int* pi = &x;
```

Now consider that `a[b]` for built in `[]` is exactly equivalent to `*(a+b)` (actually that's how `a[b]` is defined by the c++ standard). Moreover you need to recall that pointer arithmetic is only defined with pointers to elements in an array. The one exception is that you can increment a pointer to an object by `1`. You cannot dereference that pointer though.

Hence,

```
pi[1] = 10;
```

is equivalent to

```
*(pi + 1) = 10;
```

And as stated above `pi + 1` is fine. It points to one past the integer. This is what we do with `end` iterators, or generally with pointers pointing to one past the last element in an array to denote the end of an array. However, dereferencing that pointer is not defined. It does not point to an `int`. The rest of the expression isn't that relevant, because once undefined behavior is invoked anything can happen.

If you want an array, you can declare an array. Variable length arrays are not part of standard C++. If you think you need one, use `std::vector` instead.

---

> So here, I guess the behavior is undefined here;

Indeed, undefined behavior.

> &pi[1] is not owned by pi so it can be overridden?

It can't.

> Is there a way to do such a thing safely?

No, there is no way to use an array without the array.

---

There are some comments concerning a single `int` being an array or not. Also a weaker variant of your question would be "Can I use a pointer to an object as if it would point to first element of an array?". And the answer to that is: yes. A single object can be considered as an array with single element. Strictly speaking it is not, it is of different type. Though consider the next example:

```
 int sum(int* begin, int* end) { 
        int result = 0; 
        for ( ; begin != end; ++begin) result += *begin;
        return result;
 }
```

The function accumulates elements of an integer array to return the result. Now:

```
 int x = 5;
 int r = sum(&x,&x+1);
```

we can use the function to calculate the sum of all elements in what looks like a single element array, but in fact is just one single `int`. [Full example](https://godbolt.org/z/YaPxros7z). Note that `sum` has no way to tell if `begin` and `end` actually do point to elements in an array or not.

A single `int` is not an array, but depending on context it can be meaningful to view it as an array with a single element.

Comment: It appears that I thought std::vector::push_back was inserting elements in O(1) time (without copying) ALL THE TIME. So I wanted to know how this is done.

 But it looks like std::vector has a 'capacity' and actually copies elements to another array with double (implementation specific?) the current capacity when insertion exceeds the current capacity. And I tested this by creating a vector, and writing a loop which for each iteration, prints address of the first element, inserts new element to the end and I can see that address changes after capacity is increased.

Comment: So based on your answer, there is no way to 'implement' a variable length array, such as std::vector, where a new element can be inserted at the end in O(1) time for ANY insertion (all the time) in C++. Am I correct?

Comment: It is not possible in C (which has native VLA support) either. If your array/vector/whatever can be arbitrary large, it is impossible to have guaranteed O(1) time complexity for any insertion. Why is amortized O(1) not good enough for you?

Comment: @CuriousCrypto `push_back` is "amortized constant", which I guess some people might simplify to just "constant" (`O(1)`) which is dishonest in my opinion. Amortized constant means that it isn't constant on small scales, but approaches constant on average as the parameter increases.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux I see... thanks.
Another thing I have noticed while writing the test is that the address doesn't change until the capacity is increased second time, like the 'actual' initial capacity is  (std::vector::capacity * 2). Can someone verify/check this if this is implementation specific? Compiler that I have tested this in:

(GCC:G++ v12.3.1, Target: x86_64-redhat-linux, args: -std=c++11).

Comment: @CuriousCrypto The language guaranties pointer, reference and iterator stability when an insertion doesn't cause the size to exceed capacity. But when size would exceed capacity, there will be a reallocation and all pointers, references and iterators to the vector's elements are invalidated. This is by design, if you know how many elements you need ahead of time, you can `reserve` enough capacity and guarantee your elements are not moved.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux I got it, but this 'reallocation' doesn't seem to happen until second capacity change. Like if I initialize std::vector to size N and call std::vector::capacity it returns N. Address of the first element is now, say 'A'. When another element is inserted after that, std::vector::capacity returns N * 2 but address of the first element is still 'A'. The address actually changes second time, when size exceeds N * 2 and further capacity changes.

Comment: @CuriousCrypto I cannot reproduce what you report. A change in capacity means reallocations means the address of first element can be expected to change, and thats what I see here https://godbolt.org/z/1zs4E7W1E. Anyhow If you actually wanted to ask something about `std::vector`, how it reallocates, how its capacity works, I suggest you to open a new question to ask about that.

Comment: @CuriousCrypto under the hood a `std::vector` is just a dynamically allocated array of certain size, and that size is the vectors capacity. When capacity is exceeded, a new array of bigger size is allocated and all elements copied to that new array. That isnt O(1), it cannot be,  but clever allocation strategies make it amortized O(1)

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai Oh wait it actually changes, couldn't notice it due to one HEX digit change, how I have missed that! Wrong alert. I have marked this as the accepted answer, thanks.